# OR-TOOLS assign shifts sequentially

Tags: java, scheduler, or-tools

i have a problem with worker sheduling with or-tools because assigns shifts not sequentially.

On a 4-hour working day I have to assign 2 shifts to each CSC. Each turn requires at least 2 csc to be present. I want each CSC to have two consecutive assigned rounds.

I don't know which costraint to implement. Can you help me?

---

```
    //each shift must have at least 2 CSC
    int csc = 4;
    int days = 1;
    int shifts = 4;
    int shiftCSC = 2;
    IntVar[][][] shifts = new IntVar[csc][days][shifts];


    for (int n = 0; n < csc; n++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < days; d++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < shifts; s++) {
              shifts[n][d][s] = model.newIntVar(0, 1, "shift_n" + n + "d" + s + "s" + s);                   
            }
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < csc; n++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < days; d++) {
            model.addEquality(LinearExpr.sum(shifts[n][d]), shiftCSC);

        }
    }

    for (int d = 0; d < days; d++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < shifts; s++) {
           IntVar[] nursesPerShift = new IntVar[csc];    
           for (int n = 0; n < csc; n++) {
                nursesPerShift[n] = shifts[n][d][s];
           }
           model.addGreaterOrEqual(LinearExpr.sum(nursesPerShift), 2);
        }
   }

   //OUTPUT
     CSC 1 works shift 0
     CSC 1 works shift 2
     CSC 2 works shift 1
     CSC 2 works shift 3
     CSC 3 works shift 1
     CSC 3 works shift 2
     CSC 4 works shift 0
     CSC 4 works shift 3

   //expected output
     CSC 1 works shift 0
     CSC 1 works shift 1
     CSC 2 works shift 2
     CSC 2 works shift 3
     CSC 3 works shift 0
     CSC 3 works shift 1
     CSC 4 works shift 2
     CSC 4 works shift 3
```

---

Comment: So you actually have only 2 shifts then?

Comment: On a 4-hour working day I have to assign 2 shifts to each CSC. Each turn requires at least 2 csc to be present.
I want each CSC to have two consecutive assigned rounds.